# Metal spoon fell to the bottom of crockpot without me knowing it. Was making chicken soup and was cooking for 5 hours. Is it safe to eat?

Tags: soup

Accidentally left a metal spoon in the crockpot for 6 hours making chicken soup. It fell to the bottom without me knowing it. Is this harmful should I dispose of the soup?

Comment: Any idea what type of metal?

Comment: If you don't know what sort of metal, do you know of its anything unusual (old, expensive, unusually light)?

Answer (score 1):

How could this be harmful? If it's a spoon, it's meant for food. Don't throw out your soup. Go ahead and eat it. It's fine.

Comment: For a spoon made of silver or copper the question would be worth asking. Most cutlery is of course stainless steel, like many saucepans and trivially acceptable.

Comment: Still no one is armed by a cooked silver spoon. Different would be a diet base on luxury last century spoon broth :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are afraid that your spoon is made of nickel or lead then no, but that spoon probably would have made you sick before. If it made of stainless steel or silver, you should be fine.